# Zend Framework 2 cannot retrieve value from session

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm having a problem with session handling in Zend Framework 2

Why is $session->bandwidth alwas 'null' in fileAction after setting it in beaconAction?

```
public function fileAction() {
    $session = new SessionContainer();
    $bandwidth = $session->bandwidth;
    var_dump($session->bandwidth);
    die;
    $settings = $this->getSettings();
    $this->lightbox($this);
    return new ViewModel(array(
        'file' => $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('file'),
        'film_path' => $settings['film_path'],
        'poster_file' => $settings['poster_file'],
    ));
}

public function beaconAction() {
    $session = new SessionContainer();
    $bandwidth = $this->getRequest()->getQuery('bw');
    $session->bandwidth = $bandwidth;
    var_dump($session->bandwidth);
    return new ViewModel(array(
        'bandwidth' => $bandwidth
    ));
}
```

Comment: Same as here: http://www.zfforum.de/zf2-einsteigerfragen/12816-session-immer-null.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to set the namespace of your session container and check your query data
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.session.container.html#basic-usage

```
public function fileAction() {
    $session = new SessionContainer("mybeaconsession");  // <--- this
    $bandwidth = $session->bandwidth;
    var_dump($session->bandwidth);
    die;
    $settings = $this->getSettings();
    $this->lightbox($this);
    return new ViewModel(array(
        'file' => $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('file'),
        'film_path' => $settings['film_path'],
        'poster_file' => $settings['poster_file'],
    ));
}

public function beaconAction() {
    $session = new SessionContainer("mybeaconsession");     // <-- try this
    $bandwidth = $this->params('bw');                       // <-- try this
    $session->bandwidth = $bandwidth;
    var_dump($session->bandwidth);
    return new ViewModel(array(
        'bandwidth' => $bandwidth
    ));
}
```

Comment: OP already answered his/her own question in the german zf forum. he/she missed to accept the cookies.